# User Defined Functions - I am trying to create a function that uses data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, user-defined-functions

I am trying to create a function that accepts input from one parameter, but joins data from multiple tables to return a sum total of that data.

here is my code for the join that works fine:

```
select orderId, sum(itemPrice * quantity) as totalPrice
from orderItem
join item on item.itemId = orderItem.itemId
group by orderId;
```

> The orderItem table stores the data in the following columns orderId, itemId, and quantity amount of the order.

The orderId and itemId use foreign keys linking to other tables. the orderId is linked to the orders table that records usersId, order date, shipping date, and destination state.

> The itemId links to the item table that looks for the itemId and retrieves the >price of the item.

---

Here is the code I have so far for my function:

```
delimiter $$
drop function if exists orderTotal $$

CREATE FUNCTION orderTotal(totalId varchar(50))
RETURNS int
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
declare s int;
select sum(quantity) into s from orderItem where orderId = totalId;
return (s);
END $$

delimiter ;
select orderId, orderTotal(orderId) as totalPrice from orderItem group by orderID;
```

I know I am missing something and after searching all over havent found a solution that works. Please help. lol

---

My solution was simple after racking my brains. Just add the join statement to select statement. All one can do is laugh.

```
delimiter $$

drop function if exists orderTotal $$

CREATE FUNCTION orderTotal(totalId varchar(50))
RETURNS int
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
    declare s int;
    select sum(quantity * itemPrice) into s from orderItem
    join item on item.itemId = orderItem.itemId
    where orderId = totalId;
    return (s);
END $$
```

Comment: What error are you getting?  What is your question?

Comment: When I use another select statement and do return (sum(s*p)) ---- Error Message: Result consisted of more than one row-----  Its not printing out the result of price * quantity for each individual order Id. @GordonLinoff

Comment: So I discovered the answer and revised my code up top for review.